# Exit dialog not working when i go to next activity

Tags: android

I created an apk with 2 buttons.
Exit button (when pressed then show dialog if exit or not)
and button to go to next activity.
If i startthe apk and press exit then yes the apk get closed without problem
but when i press button to next activity and then go back and press exit button 
then dialog is to see but when i press YES then the appk goes to next activity and dont exit the apk.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btn133(View v) {
   //Next activity BTN
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, act22.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    //Back exit dialog
    public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
    //Exit botun
    public void bt(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="326dp"
        android:layout_height="-50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="426dp"
        android:onClick="btn133"
        android:text="btn133"

         />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="326dp"
        android:layout_height="-50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="508dp"
        android:onClick="bt"
        android:text="exit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the use of btn133?

Comment: @Muamad i did not get your actual problem but if you are facing dialog cancellation issue..so just call dialog.cancel() in both positive button click  also.

Comment: is a bottun when i press then i go to a new activity

Comment: i created the 2 bottun on main activity on is to go to new activity and one is to show exit dialog but when i go to new activity then i press exit bottun then i press yes to exit in dialog but it dont exit it goes to new activity ihope you understand

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh6MT.png)Replace your code with this

```
 @Override
    //Back exit dialog
    public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
    //Exit botun
    public void bt(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: @Muhamad Gamer give your class.. may be one parenthesis is missing in your class.

Comment: the exit dialog is working without problems when i run the apk and press exit it exit the apk since when i press the bottun to new activity then i press exit on dialog then it dont exit the apk is going to the new activity i press yes in dialog